# Vue does not render

Tags: vue.js

As per the help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299339/vuejs-layouts-and-page-components/49299561#49299395) I have created the following
app.js

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

 import App from './app.vue'
 import welcome from './components/pages/Welcome'
 import about from './components/pages/About'
 import contact from './components/pages/Contact'

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('passport-clients', require('./components/passport/Clients.vue'));
Vue.component('passport-authorized-clients', require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue'));
Vue.component('passport-personal-access-tokens', require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue'));

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  { path: '/', name: 'welcome', component: Welcome },
  { path: '/about', name: 'about', component: About },
  { path: '/contact', name: 'contact', component: Contact }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

and App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navbar v-if="isHome" />
    <router-view></router-view>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Navbar from './components/includes/Navbar.vue'
  import Footer from './components/includes/Footer.vue'
  export default{
    components: {
      'Navbar': Navbar,
      'Footer': Footer
    }
  }
</script>
```

Welcome.vue in components/pages folder

```
<template>
  <div>
  <h3>This is the Index page</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {}
</script>
```

Navbar component in components/includes folder

```
<template>
  <div>
  <h3>This is the Navbar</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {}
</script>
```

Similarly i have created all other pages, navbar, footer components. When i run npm run dev it says build successful. When i visit the localhost:800 url the vue doesn't render. Chrome inspector console tab shows Uncaught ReferenceError: Welcome is not defined

Also do i need to delete the index route from web.php

Comment: You imported as `welcome` and used it as `Welcome`

Comment: @Doblel I feel like an idiot. You're right. Changing it to Welcome showed the Welcome view. But it shows the welcome page and footer, not the navbar. How to solve this?

Comment: No problem, here to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScipt is case sensitive and variable "welcome" is not the same as "Welcome".

```
import welcome from './components/pages/Welcome'
{ path: '/', name: 'welcome', component: Welcome },
```

Change to:

```
{ path: '/', name: 'welcome', component: welcome },
```

and it should work. Do the same with the rest of the variables - about and contact.

Comment: Now the navbar does not render it only shows welcome component and footer. i updated the code

Comment: <Navbar v-if="isHome" /> this line says that Navbar should only be shown if "isHome" is truthy. I do not see it defined therefor it could be "undefined" which is falsy.

Comment: Yes That's the error shows in chrome console. So do i need to define it in export default?

Comment: You can either do that or remove the v-if="isHome" if you want to show Navbar always. Also if you like the answer please consider accepting it.

Comment: Great! Thanks. It says you can accept the answer after 5 mins. So im waiting to accept it

Comment: One last question. In Navbar component i have anchor tags with href. I see in a tutorial to use router-link Should i change all the anchor tags with router-link? Sorry for too many questions

Comment: Yes if you want to just change the component inside <router-view></router-view> (based on the route). This will not make new request to the server. If you want to make new request and refresh whole page then use <a>

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problems, happy to help :)